# Suggestion for a beginner's Partial DE Book

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-derivative, book-recommendation

I am studying Partial DE for my Master.

I face a lot of difficulties in understanding them. It is the first time I am studying in my academic studies.

My main goal is to understand when systems are well placed, to be able to solve Cauchy problems, IV problems, and like this. I would like the book contains examples with solutions.

I have looked at other posts here but instead of helping me, they have confused me more in my choice.

I would like to ask if there is a good book for a beginner, written as simply as possible, in Partial DE.

Preferred to be an e-book.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I would recommend Strauss' book:  https://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Walter-Strauss/dp/0470054565/ref=sr_1_1?crid=VZCFPLO2UO70&keywords=partial+differential+equations+strauss&qid=1671754814&s=books&sprefix=partial+differential+equations+stra%2Cstripbooks%2C150&sr=1-1

Comment: @GReyes There is also open access! Thank you